# Where is the Eclipse Java home directory?

Tags: eclipse, pydev

Im trying to install pydev using the [official tutorial](http://pydev.org/manual_101_install.html) My issue is that i can not locate my java.home directory. I have checked Applications/eclipse to no avail.

> The second step is discovering the java being used in Eclipse: go to
>   Help > About > Installation details and look for 'java.home'
>
> **Then to actually import it, in the command line, go to the Eclipse
>   'java.home' directory and execute**
>
> bin/keytool.exe -import -file pydev_certificate.cer -keystore
>   lib/security/cacerts

Can anyone tell me the path to this? what am i missing?

Thanks

Comment: They are telling you how to find this - look for the `java.home` entry in the `Configuration` tab of the dialog displayed by `Help > About > Installation Details`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to **Help menu**-> **About submenu** -> **Installation Details button** -> **Configuration tab**. Find the java.home configuration setting in the **text area**. Go to that directory specified by java.home and you'll find the bin folder where java utilities reside. One of them is keytool.exe that is used for generating certificates. In your command line go to that directory.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse is using JRE/JDK specified in it's configuration (if not provided in `eclipse.ini`). Open preferences window (menu `Window -> Preferences`). Then go to `Java -> Installed JREs` and in the right panel you'll see all JREs. In `Location` column you'll see path which points to the `JAVA_HOME` directory.

Answer (score 0):

@Deepend, you need to CD to the "java.home" Directory prior to using the Keytool (and type the command appropriately for the Shell). That is what those Instructions are asking you to do.

If you have Java 7 on WinXP open a CMD Window then type this (otherwise, adjust for your OS):

cd "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7"

bin\keytool.exe -import -file pydev_certificate.cer -keystore lib/security/cacerts

Hint: PW may be "changeit" if you never changed it and it goes without saying that you likely need to add a Path prior to the word "pydev_certificate.cer".